# Python -- Quotations around filenames

Tags: python

I'm not quite sure when I need to put quotations around the filenames in Python.
For example, when I set

```
f = open(file)
```

I can run something like

```
len(f.read())
```

and it will run fine.
However, when I do it directly, it only works with

```
len(open("file").read())
```

Likewise, in terminal when running from Python I always have to use quotations.
What is the 'rule' when using quotations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python you can always use the name of a variable or function outside quotations, but the name of a file is usually not a variable.

If file is the name of a string variable you can always do `open(file).read()`, however if it is literally the filename you must always do `open("file").read()`.

Answer (score 0):

Quotations indicate a string literal constant.  No quotations indicate that you're referencing a variable, which may itself be a string (in this case, populated with the path to a file).